# how to schedule a procedure inside a package with parameters in oracle

Tags: oracle11g

I have a package called mypackage, which has a procedure myproc. The procedure myproc accepts two date parameters. After receiving the parameters it does some comparison and retrieves the data. Now my question is how we can schedule this procedure myproc which is inside a package mypackage with two i/p parameters?

I am using oracle11g and I have both sys and normal user access.

A demo example will be of great help.

Answer (score 0):

Details here: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/scheduse002.htm#i1009668

You care create the job as:

```
 BEGIN
     DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_JOB (
        job_name            =>  'my_new_job', 
        program_name        =>  'mapackage.myproc', 
        schedule_name       =>  'my_schedule');
 END;
```

Then set the arguments as:

```
 BEGIN
    DBMS_SCHEDULER.SET_JOB_ARGUMENT_VALUE (
    job_name                => 'my_new_job',
    argument_position       => 1,
    argument_value          => '27-NOV-12');
 END;
```

/